# BarButtonItem With Popovercontroller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a BarButtonItem and a Popovercontroller. the question is who can i pop something when i click on the button can some one help me. i will post some code what i have on this moment.

> -(void) showPop:(id)sender{
>       NSLog(@"test");

```
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]  initWithContentViewController:popover];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    //self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Nieuws", @"Nieuws");
    /*if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }*/



}
 return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_loading = NO;

self.title = @"Agenda";

if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

    EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
    view.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView addSubview:view];
    _refreshHeaderView = view;
}

//  update the last update date


self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bar-bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

[_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(66.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging: self.tableView];


//[self loadData];

 //[popButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showPop)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might just be a typo but when you create your button, the selector should be showPop: (with a colon) not showPop.